# troubleshooting sql to object mapping entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

**My question is:**

How to debug the ***mapping process*** from the records that are returned from SQL Server as it is mapped to the class object such that I can tell exactly which class property is failing?

**Background:**

Getting an error when returning data from SQL Server as it tries to map the sql data to the object. I am using Entity Framework 6 and Automapper projection for what it's worth.

The error I get is `The cast to value type 'System.Int32' failed because the materialized value is null. Either the result type's generic parameter or the query must use a nullable type.`.

***I know that it means one of the columns from the SQL is returning NULL that it is trying to map to an class property that in `int` and not nullable***. But, how can you tell *which property is the problem*?

The query that EF creates is massive (1,250 lines) with lots of generic columns such as `C1`, `C2`, etc. It seems the column order, for the named columns it does returned are in alphabetical order, sort of...so I took all the class properties and sorted them in alpha order to see if they'd match up to the column order...they sort of do, but not 100%...plus the class inherits from another...not sure if it includes those in the alpha sort, or at the end, etc.

Anyway, that was my attempt to figure out which property is the problem. The query does have several fields that are null, but there are lots of fields and many string and nullable int, etc, so those could be valid. Even trying to figure out if the column `C1` returns null, which actual property it is trying to map to is near impossible with this very large query and a class with 80+ fields.

Is there anyway to break down the sql to object mapping to know exactly which property is the problem?

Comment: I might be over simplifying this but this should be design driven. The actual data is conflicting with your code so I would think you would need to take a second look at the design and make any fields nullable that are, well, nullable.

Comment: @Chad, how about logging and tracing your query. See: https://cmatskas.com/logging-and-tracing-with-entity-framework-6/  and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/logging-and-interception

Comment: @Jamal, I did that in SQL Profiler, but the results have lots of generic columns (i.e. `[Project1].[C1]`) that get returned, so it's hard to know which column is being mapped to which `int` class property.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils yes, or fixing the query to return a value instead of null. But I can't do that if I can't determine which column is the problem to rework it :)

Comment: @Chad, I think the following may help: https://entityframework.net/how-to-see-ef-errors.

Comment: @Jamal, thank you, but we do that on Saving data to capture the entity validation errors, but looking for the same thing on a `Select`. The query runs fine, but something after the query is returned and mapped to the object is where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might be something like this.

Your DB model:
`public int property { get; set; }`

Has you may know, int is a struct and its value can't be null.
Where mapper is serializing the data, it throws an Exception because that column in the DB is probably null.

One thing you can do to check is make the int nullable, as such:
`public int? property { get; set; }`

Maybe you could use SQL Profiler from SQL Server and check.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond, but my question was about how to determine which property is failing in the mapping. As I stated, I know why I'm getting the error in general, but am looking for a way to troubleshoot the mapping process itself.